# How can I get data inside of Vue from database like config or smth>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```javascript
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        positions: []
    },

    created() {

        axios.get('/config').then(function(response) {
            this.$set(this.positions, "positions", response.data[0].dragedPositions);
        });

        console.log(this.positions.positions);
    }

});
```

I have configs for my app in database and I want to use them inside of Vue instance (here are positions of my elements). But when im getting "this.positions.positions" Im getting empty string.. How can I do that?

Comment: do you understand that ajax request is asynchronous? also replace `function(response) {` with `(response) => {`.

Comment: Yep I know that. Is there way to do It synchronous then or how to retrive data other way?
 
I managed bind(this) instead. But its not working anyway. I just can't get this data inside this instance. In other component It's easy working. I'm trying to save data to localStorage but its not the way I want.

Comment: yes you can make it synchronous, but you should not. there are better ways. but i don't understand the problem since you can load the data, so what do this mean *"I just can't get this data inside this instance."*.

Comment: This data is visible only in components and is not in Vue created() mounted() methods() functions. So I can't use this data in those functions but I need it in here.

Comment: So load config first and bootstrap app after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to load config first and bootstrap application after that. Use [propsData](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#propsData) for this:

```javascript
axios.get('/config').then(function(response) {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    props: ['positions'],
    propsData: {
      positions: response.data[0].dragedPositions
    },
    created() {
      console.log(this.positions);
    }
  });
});
```

I even created little demo :)

```js
const axios = {get () {
  return Promise.resolve({data: [{dragedPositions: [1,2]}]})
}}

axios.get("/config").then(function(response) {
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    props: ['positions'],
    propsData: {
      positions: response.data[0].dragedPositions
    },
    created() {
      console.log('created hook', this.positions);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<pre id="app">positions = {{ positions }}</pre>
```

Comment: That's what I wanted! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this trick? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```
var self = this;    
axios.get('/config').then(function(response) {
    self.$set(self.positions, "positions", response.data[0].dragedPositions);
});
```

By the way, It seems that you should initialize your `positions` as an object instead of an array.

Comment: I did  "bind(this)" and It's working. The problem is I can't get the data inside the instance. but I need it. In other component the data is available.

I'm now working with localStorage but It's not the way I want to do that.

Comment: sorry, but I cannot get your point. The data will be available once axios's callback invoked. Where do you want to get it from?

Comment: I need this data inside functions mounted() created() etc. In this solution I can't get this data in there. I can only take it in components

Comment: @Canor why not chain the promise?